# _joinData not updating request correctly in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, controller, request

I am trying to create an associated table, where I've exam_id and question_id that are linked with belongsToMany relationship through an ExamsQuestions table that has belongsTo relationship on both of them.

I've created the (atleast some of the) relations correctly, as I can save the ids correctly, but I've in the associative table also fields "questionPoints" and "isActive" fields, but they're not updating.

I use .js file to send [a run-time request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzcQV.png)

But when I'm getting [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWQYS.png) from the controller function, the joindata is not set to the objects correctly.

in Database the rows are not updated at all, even though some of the ._joindata information is applied (ids). I think this is CakePHP's built-in association that does the joining, as 1 level of associations is applied by default.

In ExamsController I first send data to the view, in order to render the view correctly. After that I use the request data to patch entity and save the entity.

```
public function take($id)
{
    if ($this->request->is('get'))
    {
        $exam = $this->Exams->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['ExamTemplates' => ['Questions.Answers']]
    ]);     
        $users = $this->Exams->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $examTemplates = $this->Exams->ExamTemplates->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);           
        $this->set(compact('exam', 'users', 'examTemplates'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $exam = $this->Exams->get($id, ['contain' => ['Questions']]);
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $exam = $this->Exams->patchEntity($exam, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Exams->save($exam)) { 
            $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => __("exam updated"),
                'this' => $this->request->data,
            ];
            $exam_id = $_POST['id'];
            $this->Flash->success(__('The exam has been updated.'));
        } else {

            $response = [
                'success' => false,
                'error' => $exam->errors(),
                'request' => $this->request->data,
                'message' => __("Error creating template")
            ];
        }
        $this->response->body(json_encode($response));
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed the problem, but I don't know if the fix was done the most correct way.

Instead of updating the field in AJAX call, I changed the _joinData update to happen in the controller based on request data.

So I just declared a new _joinData as new array and gave it the fields that were not automatically added. One thing to note is that if I gave it any field manually that CakePHP does autocomplete, it would also not update.